# QGIS zonal statistics only non zero values

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, zonal-statistics, nodata

I have a raster layer and a polygon layer. The raster layer has values between 0 and 600. I want to calculate the average of all values above 0 within each polygon.

The only solution I came up with so far is to clip the part of the polygons that overlaps with a non-zero (positive) raster value, and then calculate the zonal statistic only for the clipped part. Since the data is quite large, this method is not practical.

Is there a faster way, e.g. set the grid values = 0 to NODATA (if this is possible) and then calculate the average value? Unfortunately I have little experience with raster data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert raster pixels with value `0` to `nodata` cells using [Raster Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_analysis.html#raster-calculator). Divide the raster's value by itself: a division by `0` will return `nodata`.

For all other pixels, to keep the value as it is, divide the pixel value by itself and multiply it again by itself.

- `5 / 5 * 5` -> `5`
- `0 / 0 * 0` -> `NODATA`

Use this expression in raster calculator, where `raster` is the name of your raster layer:

`"raster@1" / "raster@1" * "raster@1"`